# Installing Braking Resistor on Dayton DC motor controller

Tags: motor-controller

I'm installing a DC motor with a Dayton Motor speed controller and I'm slightly confused on the wiring instructions. The instructions have one wire of the resistor going to the terminal designated for the negative wire of the motor. Does the braking resistor just share the terminal with the negative wire of the motor? Dayton motor controller model is 2M171.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about motor and controller? We are not all Dayton motor speed controller experts.

Comment: Of course! The speed controller is a 120VAC variable speed controller for a DC motor. It comes with an optional braking resistor. I have limited experience with DC motors and speed controllers so the wiring diagram is confusing me. Installation instructions has the resistor connecting to the same terminal that I connect the negative wire of the motor to. Normally I wouldn't connect 2 wires to the same terminal but I'm not entirely familiar with wiring braking resistors. Should I just go ahead and put it on the same terminal as the negative connection of the DC motor like the diagrams?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this connection sounds plausible to me. During break, the resistor is connected parallel to the motor, one permanent connection to the negative motor contact is fine.

If the installation instructions say you should wire it this way, then you should. It might not be this way for every controller, but it is this way for this controller.